# When does braintree drop in ui create payment method nonce?

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, braintree

I'm trying to integrate Braintree Drop In UI into a meteor app I'm working on. I've gotten the server to create a token for the client to create the drop in container. However I can't get it to create a payment method nonce. I'm using the callback for the nonce is created, but it isn't triggering when I submit.

This is the code for the container.

```
braintree.setup(response, 'dropin', {
  container: 'dropin-container',
  onPaymentMethodReceived: function(data) {
      Meteor.call('createCustomer', data.nonce);
  }
});
```

And this is the meteor event for submitting the form.

```
Template.reservePage.events({
    'submit #paymentForm': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        FlowRouter.go('/dashboard');
        console.log("submitted");
    }
});
```

Is there supposed to be a method to call to trigger braintree to create a nonce?

Comment: If you solved your own problem, don't edit the question with the solution. Instead, post your solution as an actual answer below and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

The issue was that the drop in was wrapped in another form inside the original form that was there. So when I submitted, it didn't register that the form it was in was submitted. Make sure it's only inside the one form!